# "Freshman", "sophomore", what next?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know first and second year undergraduate students are freshmen and sophomores respectively.

- Are there similar terms for third and fourth years, given most programmes are three or four year programmes?
- If no, is there any reason for coining a word only for the second year (i.e., *sophomore*)?

Comment: Third-half & Fourth-half, by logical extension. There are no names continuing on past *sophomore* in the original list which was only for two.

Comment: Er... I actually wanted to ask why sophomore coming from sophistry applies only to second-years. OK, I shall ask another question...

Comment: That's a much better way to put it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Junior is the third grade.
Senior is the fourth grade.